# Convert data read from a file to a variable in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I have a problem - I am writing in a file in Haskell (I wanna write a sentence in the file and everytime I write in it I want to overwrite the content of the file so this func does the work for me completely fine)

```
writeFunc message = writeFile file message where
    file = "abc.txt"
```

And then reading from the same file

```
readFunc = do
    let file = "abc.txt"
    contents <- readFile file
    return contents
```

And then I wanna save the things I have read in a variable:

In the terminal doing this

```
let textFromAFile = readFunc
```

results into this:

```
*Main> let textFromAFile = readFunc
*Main> textFromAFile
"okay"
```

But when I use `let textFromAFile = readFunc` inside my code, the code wont compile

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tree.hs, interpreted )

tree.hs:109:29: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

I wanna save it in a variable so I can use it later in other functions. Why it works in the terminal but wont compile and what I can do to make it work? ReadFunc returns IO String and is there a possible way to convert it to s String so I can use it in a pure func?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readFunc` has type `IO String`, you can use it in another `IO` expression with:

```
someIO = do
    textFromAFile <- readFunc
    -- use textFromFile (String) …
    -- …
```

for example:

```
someIO = do
    textFromAFile <- readFunc
    writeFunc (textFromAFile ++ "/")
```

The reason it works in the GHCi terminal is that the terminal evaluates `IO a` objects, so while `textFromAFile` is an `IO String`, and the terminal will thus *evaluate* `textFromAFile`.

Comment: I wanna use this textFromAFile so I can concat it with other things and then overwrite it in the same file

Comment: something like that

someIO = do
    textFromAFile <- readFunc
    let newText = textFromAFile ++ "/"
    writeFunc newText

Comment: but i get this error *** Exception: abc.txt: openFile: resource busy (file is locked)

Comment: @Vanessa: if you have a function that concatenates, you can use `writeFunc (someFunction textFromAFile)` on the line below `textFromAFile <- readFunc`, with `someFunction` a function that maps the `String` (from the file) to a `String` (that will be written back to the file).

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: @Vanessa: ah, but that is because your `readFile` is lazy. You can use it from `System.IO.Strict` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.4.0.1/docs/System-IO-Strict.html#v:readFile) to read it eagerly.

Comment: Now I get this

[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( tree.hs, interpreted )

tree.hs:1:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `System.IO.Strict'
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: @Vanessa: you need to install the `strict` package.